# Errors when creating a formula column in oracle report builder

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, reportbuilder

I'm new in pl/sql and I'm trying to create formula column in oracle report builder as I don't know where to declare this variable and I get these error.

Here is my code:

```
function CF_AMOUNT_TO_WORDFormula return Char is


 V_CONV varchar2(2000);

 begin
```

Here is the problem (I think):

```
V_CONV:=XX_CONVERT_NUM_TO_WORDS_NEW(:C_AMOUNT_POL_TOTAL,:poh_currency_code);            

RETURN V_CONV;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN RETURN NULL;
end;
```

... and I get below error:

> Error 201 :identifier 'XX_CONVERT_NUM_TO_WORDS_NEW' must be declared

Comment: Well where is XX_CONVERT_NUM_TO_WORDS_NEW' located? In the same schema?  Also, NEVER use a when others like that.  you will get errors and not know about it

Comment: yes in the same schema

Comment: Oracle disagrees with you. Can you prove it? Please, connect to that schema in SQL*Plus and execute `select xxx_convert_num_to_words_new(100, value_that_represents_some_currency_code) from dual` and post the result back here. Make sure to connect to the same schema as you did in Reports Builder.

Comment: clean-up crew is done...  active edit approval waiting for this post...

Comment: @Michael... how can you approve this badly formatted question... if **"I'm new in..."** is in the title?????

Comment: @Akshay Nevrekar... how can you approve this badly formatted question... if **"I'm new in..."** is in the title?????